# Lisp program that creates a sublist with each increment

Tags: list, syntax, lisp, common-lisp, sublist

I'm currently working on a program that increments through a list and creates a sublist within a list for each time it's incremented. for example if I had a list of

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

. Then I want to increment through it and create

```
(1 (2 (3 (4 (5 (6))))))
```

. So far I have:

```
(defun INCREMENT (L) (unless (endp L) (cons (list (first L)) (INC (rest L)))))
```

but all this will return is

```
((1) (2) (3) (4))
```

I know it's just increment the number of times list is used along with going through the elements of the list but I'm still kind of learning the syntax of Lisp. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Meant to put INCREMENT before rest L

Comment: What do you mean by "increment"?

Comment: at the end there's a syntactical issue if you name it INC and not INCREMENT in order to get it to recurse

Comment: “Increment” usually means to increase a number.  This is a bit confusing.  Of course, naming things is hard.  Maybe `nest`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, the trick is to use `list` *before* calling the recursion. Also notice that we must handle the base cases: when the list is empty and when there's only one element left:

```
(defun INCREMENT (L)
  (cond ((endp L) '())
        ((endp (rest L)) (list (first L)))
        (t (cons (first L)
                 (list (INCREMENT (rest L)))))))
```